# Reading data from file using DataProvider in testng

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Let's say I have a text file with the following data

```
username=testuser
password=testpassword
email=test@test.com
address=testaddress
zipcode=12345
```

Or I have an XML with the following data

```
<TestData>
   <UserInfo>
       <username>testuser</username>
       <password>testpassword</password>
       <email>test@test.com</email>
       <address>testaddress</address>
   </UserInfo>
</TestData>
```

I have a test as below

```
public class DPTest {

   @Test(dataprovider="testdp")
   public void userTest_01(String username, String Password) {

   //Test goes here

   }
}
```

Another class

```
public class DPTest2 {

   @Test(dataprovider="testdp")
   public void userTest_02(String email, String address, String password) {

   //Test goes here

   }
}
```

Can my dataprovider read the values from the above mentioned text file or XML and supply it to the test methods?

As per my understanding the data provider is going to read all the lines in the text file and supply it to the test method and throw an error saying "data provider is trying to provide 6 parameters but Test can only accept 2 parameter" ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.
You can create an annotation to specify the parameters this DataProvider should load from your XML.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface XmlParameters {
   String[] value();    
}

@Test(dataProvider = "XMLFileLoader")
@XmlParameters({"username", "password"})
public void testSomething(String username, String password) {
    // implementation omitted for brevity
}

@DataProvider(name = "XMLFileLoader")
public static Object[][] getDataFromXmlFile(final Method testMethod) {
    XmlParameters parameters = testMethod.getAnnotation(XmlParameters.class);
    String[] fields = parameters.value();
    //load just the fields you want
    return new Object[][] { { "user1", "pass1" } };
}
```

This code is not "production ready", you should check if the annotation is not null before reading the values, and is probably better move the interface and the logic to load your xml to another class, so you can reuse on another tests.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, you are looking at data provider in the wrong way. Please refer to the testNG documentation. http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

You goal can be achieved by something like the code below. `Test` class contains test method. it gets data from a dataprovider specified inside another class `TestData`. In `TestData` class we define method for accessing data from a file/xml and return it as an 'Object[][]' in '@DataProvider' method

```
public class Test {
   @Test(dataProvider="testData" dataProviderclass = TestData.class)
   public void userTest(TestData testData) {
       //Test code goes here
   }
}

public class TestData {

   private String username;
   private String password;

   public void setUsername(String username) {
       this.username = username;
   }

   public String getUsername() {
       return username;          
   }

   public void setPassword(String password) {
       this.password = password;
   }

   public String getPassword() {
       return password;
   }

   @DataProvider(name="testData")
   public static Object[][] userTestData (TestData testData) {           
       //Code to read from file/xml
       TestData testData = new TestData();
       testData.setUsername("Get from file/xml");
       testData.setPassword("Get from file/xml")

       return new Object{{testData}}
   }
}
```

Comment: I know we can do it using the getters and setters for a couple of fields. But let's say I have thousands of test data and  I have them all in one file. So dynamically my test case should be able to consume the test data from the data provider. It's possible using the answers above you from "tiagohngl"