# It's suitable to use data provider to read more then 100 data from excel sheet?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, junit, testng

It's suitable to use data provider to read more than 100 data from Excel sheet?

How can I pass my data into test scripts without passing this many variables in test method?

I have to fetch 100+ data from a row of Excel so for this I would have to pass 100+ variables in `@test` annotation. Also I have multiple rows.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There's no explicit limit on number of parameter rows according to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters, as well as for size of `Object[][]` array. So, the answer to your question is -
 yes, you can fetch 100+ rows.

Refer to this example of overall approach: [Reading data from file using DataProvider in testng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067577/reading-data-from-file-using-dataprovider-in-testng?rq=1)
Just add proper XLS parsing to your `@DataProvider` method

Comment: hi Ivan, it's fesiable to do llike this taking100+ data from excel sheet into  dataprovider and pass all those parameter in test method ?

Comment: Yes, and the test method will execute every-time with different data